# Aligning equations

Tags: align

This is very similar to a lot of other questions but I haven't found one that EXACTLY replicates the problem I'm having.  I have the following:

```
\begin{align*}
  &\text{minimize} &R_k + \sum_jr_{jk}^+ + r_{jk}^- &\\
  &\text{subject to} &R_k + r_{jk}^+ \geq \hat{\gamma_{jk}}X_jk, &\forall j ,k\\
  & &R_k + r_{jk}^- \geq -\hat{\gamma_{jk}}X_jk, &\forall j,k \\
  & &R_k, r_{jk}^+, r_{jk}^- \geq 0 &\forall j,k
\end{align*}
```

Ultimately I want my output to have the text line up in the "first column", the `R_k` values to line up in the second column, and all the forall statements to line up in the third.  Note that none of the lines have all three items (*i.e.* the last two should have some leading white space).

Right now my output has the text and the forall's lining up but the `R_k` terms are scattered.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `align` and `align*` environments, columns are alternately justified right, left, right, left, etc. If you want two adjacent columns to both be aligned left (or right), use `&&` rather than `&` to separate them. This might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
\begin{align*}
 & \text{minimize}   && R_k + \sum_jr_{jk}^+ + r_{jk}^-             &&             \\
 & \text{subject to} && R_k + r_{jk}^+ \geq  \hat{\gamma_{jk}}X_jk, && \forall j,k \\
 &                   && R_k + r_{jk}^- \geq -\hat{\gamma_{jk}}X_jk, && \forall j,k \\
 &                   && R_k,  r_{jk}^+, r_{jk}^- \geq 0             && \forall j,k
\end{align*}
```