# How to achieve two levels of indentation inside align environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, indentation

I'm trying to indent an equation further away - basically to achieve two levels of indentation.
Let me explain a little bit more...

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\begin{document}

        Suppose we want to compute $\nu(u_1)$, we first consider $Y_1$.\\ So $Y_1=A\setminus S_1=\{country, genre\}$, and we have that:\\
        \begin{align*}
        \nu(u_1)&=\exists(country, genre)(u\,'_1\wedge u\,'_2\wedge u\,'_3)\\
        &=\exists(country, genre)(\varphi\,'_1(cd, member, band)\wedge\\
        &\varphi\,'_2(cd,member, date)\wedge\\
        &\varphi\,'_3(cd, member,country))
        \end{align*}

        We now want to prove that similarity conditions hold for these three functions we defined.\\

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Now, what I want is to indent the third and fourth lines in this equation further, so they will be aligned with the `\varphi\,'_1`.

I tried to adopt the approach suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124140/aligning-equations), and added double && to add a level of indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\begin{document}

        Suppose we want to compute $\nu(u_1)$, we first consider $Y_1$.\\ So $Y_1=A\setminus S_1=\{country, genre\}$, and we have that:\\
        \begin{align*}
        \nu(u_1)&=\exists(country, genre)(u\,'_1\wedge u\,'_2\wedge u\,'_3)\\
        &=\exists(country, genre)(&&\varphi\,'_1(cd, member, band)\wedge\\
        &   &&\varphi\,'_2(cd,member, date)\wedge\\
        &   &&\varphi\,'_3(cd, member,country))
        \end{align*}

        We now want to prove that similarity conditions hold for these three functions we defined.\\

\end{document}
```

But this produced bad output:

[image]

Although the three `\varphi`'s are now aligned together, they are unnecessarily pushed further away to the right, and this is obviously not what I intended...

How can I achieve second level of indention correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\begin{document}

        Suppose we want to compute $\nu(u_1)$, we first consider $Y_1$.\\ 
So $Y_1=A\setminus S_1=\{\mathit{country}, \mathit{genre}\}$, and we have that:\\
        \begin{align*}
        \nu(u_1)&=\exists(\mathit{country}, \mathit{genre})(u\,'_1\wedge u\,'_2\wedge u\,'_3)\\
        &=\exists(\mathit{country}, \mathit{genre})(
\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&\varphi\,'_1(\mathit{cd}, \mathit{member}, band)\wedge\\
&        \varphi\,'_2(\mathit{cd},\mathit{member}, date)\wedge\\
&        \varphi\,'_3(\mathit{cd}, \mathit{member},\mathit{country}))
\end{aligned}
        \end{align*}

        We now want to prove that similarity conditions hold for these 
three functions we defined.

\end{document}
```

You can use `split` or `aligned` within the `align` but note don't use math italic for multi-letter identifiers, and don't end a paragraph with `\\`

Comment: @yo' yes done (didn't remake image)

Comment: @so.very.tired Please remark that the answer got edited, `\!` was added before `\begin{aligned}` to remove the spurious space.

Comment: note that the `\!` is not needed any more in recent `amsmath` releases (although it is OK to leave it there, it does not affect the spacing)

Answer (score 1):

The result can likewise be obtained from the OP's 1st MWE by simply making the `\varphi` lines a `\Longunderstack`, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}

        Suppose we want to compute $\nu(u_1)$, we first consider $Y_1$.\\ So $Y_1=A\setminus S_1=\{country, genre\}$, and we have that:\\
        \begin{align*}
        \nu(u_1)&=\exists(country, genre)(u\,'_1\wedge u\,'_2\wedge u\,'_3)\\
        &=\exists(country, genre)(\Longunderstack[l]{
          \varphi\,'_1(cd, member, band)\wedge\\
          \varphi\,'_2(cd,member, date)\wedge\\
          \varphi\,'_3(cd, member,country))
        }
        \end{align*}

        We now want to prove that similarity conditions hold for these three functions we defined.\\

\end{document}
```

[image]