# Why are tags missing in alignment sublevels?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, lists, options, tags

I would like to have integer tags all the way on the right hand side of each equation line.

I also need multiple alignment(horizontal) levels.

#### Attempt 01: Michelle Krummel's Lists tutorial

```
\begin{enumerate}  
\item  
    \begin{align}  
        \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]  
    \end{align}  
\item  
    \begin{align}  
        \frac{d}{dx}[g(x)]  
    \end{align}  
\item  
    \begin{itemize}  
        \item  
            \begin{align}  
                \frac{d}{dx}[h(x)]  
            \end{align}  
            \item  
            \begin{itemize}  
                \item  
                    \begin{itemize}  
                        \item  
                            \begin{align}  
                                \frac{d}{dx}[A(x)]  
                            \end{align}  
                        \item  
                            \begin{align}  
                                \frac{d}{dx}[H(x)]  
                            \end{align}  
                    \end{itemize}  
            \end{itemize}  
\end{itemize}  
\end{enumerate}
```

This way does produce an effect very close to what I want to do, except for the list numbering, bulleting, "dash", and "star" on the left hand side, Please see graphic below (towards bottom) within "CURRENT RESULTS" link under "Attempt 01: Lists".

This is a result of `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}`, but without it the `\item` trick just doesn't work. 
However, I find having to write the following clauses for each successive indentation a tad bit onerous:

```
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
            \begin{itemize}
                ...
            \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
```

The next two attempts I use: [How to achieve two levels of indentation inside align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220523/how-to-achieve-two-levels-of-indentation-inside-align-environment)
On this page there are two solutions: 2) Steven B. Segletes and 3) David Carlisle

#### Attempt 02: Segletes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Andrew}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    Proove Theorem AAC
        \begin{align}
            \mbox{Let y } & = \Longunderstack[l] {
                f(x)        \\
                g(x)    
                }           \\
                    x & = \Longunderstack[l] {
                    h(x)        \\
                    %w & = \Longunderstack[l] {
                    %   A(x)        \\
                    %   }   
                    }
        \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

This works well for two levels of alignment, but notice how above I had to comment out the third level of alignment.  You can't use the `\Longunderstack[l]` within another `\Longunderstack`, thus only two levels of alignment.

#### Attempt 03: David Carlisle

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Andrew}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        Carlisle &              \\                  
             &Sample Explanation        \\   
                \nu(u_1)&= f(x)                                     \\  %Alignment Level 1
                                &= \cosh(x) - \sinh(x)      \\  %Alignment Level 1
                                & G(x) =
            \!\begin{aligned}[t]
                    & A(x)              \\                              %Alignment Level 2
                    & H(x) = \int^Q_O z(x) dx   \\      %Alignment Level 2
                    & L(x) =                                                %Alignment Level 2 
                    \!\begin{aligned}[t]
                        & \frac{d}{dx} P(x)                     \\          %Alignment Level 3 
                        & S(x)                                                              %Alignment Level 3
                    \end{aligned}
                \end{aligned}
        \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Carlisle's method better matches my purpose than Segletes' method because you can utilize `\!\begin{aligned}[t]` recursively, thus it seems that there is no limitation on the number of alignment levels.

[image: CURRENT RESULTS]

But notice that only the first 4 lines are tagged with integers 1-4.  TAGS 5-7 aren't there since Carlisle's method uses {aligned} for sub-alignment levels, and this naturally disables tagging.  I was wondering if I may have integer tags for the last few lines 5-end while preserving the present alignment.  Anything else beside {aligned}[t] that can execute sub-alignment levels?

[image: TARGET RESULTS]

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you show a graphic of what you're after?

Comment: ...by the way, I see tags with each `align`.

Comment: I see tags with each too, but not  at each line defined with `aligned`, as expected. off-topic: why you need to load `amsmath` twice + `mathtools` three times?

Comment: Werner,  I looked for a place to upload pdf files, but apparently there is no place to upload images.  I did however find a way to embed links to pictures (https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).  Perhaps you can share with me on how to do this.

Comment: Werner, I have found how to upload images, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Zarko, I see your point with repeating the \usepackage{amsmath} (total 2 times), good catch!  However, I don't see any instances of the line "\usepackage{mathtools}" three times.

Comment: @afc888ny: Okay, so you uploaded some images, all of which show integer tags on the right side of the page. But the question is still not clear how that is somehow wrong...

Comment: ...could you describe the type of alignment you're after?

Comment: Werner, You stated "all of which show integer tags on the right side of the page.". Please look at Attempt 03 Carlisle picture again, it is clear that the last few lines [H,L,S(x)] HAVE NO TAGS. Thus not "all" lines have tags. Actually you can see clearly that tags only exist from 1-4. Again, there are no tags #5-end. Here is where the problem lies.

Comment: Alignment: Currently the alignment for the Carlisle example(picture above) is perfect. I'm just missing tags for H(x), L(x) and S(x).  I edited my question a few times, please re-read the entire question again.

Answer (score 1):

the whole point of `aligned` is that these are "subsidiary" equations, and thus only one of them gets a number.

`alignat` can be called on to assign additional alignment points.  some of the wider lines at the top of the group may have to be "finished off" with `\mathrlap` to lose the extra width.

here's one possibility (much of the content is stolen from the carlisle example):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{3}
    First &              \\                  
      &Second        \\   
        \nu(u_1)&= f(x)   \\
                &= \mathrlap{\cosh(x) - \sinh(x) }     \\
                & G(x) ={} & A(x) &              \\
                &          & H(x) &= \int^Q_O z(x) dx   \\
                &          & L(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} P(x)  \\
                &          &      &= S(x)
  \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

another possibility is to manually position the "nested" levels with appropriate `\phantom`s.  that is left as an exercise.

Comment: This solves my problem in its entirety.

Comment: i'm glad that this is solved.  you can recognize that by accepting the answer -- clicking on the check mark below the voting "arrows".